# Image processing in languages other than c and matlab

Tags: c++, image-processing

It seems like most image processing apps are done using matlab or OpenCV using C++.
Are there any other languages  providing good image processing libraries?? How do they compare to matlab and opencv?

When I say languages I mean something like Java , python or even perl!

Comment: Have you some examples of your needs?

Comment: Birds do it, bees do, even educated Javascripters do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image libraries exist for many languages

- Lisp:
  ch-image
  http://cyrusharmon.org/static/projects/ch-image/doc/ch-image.xhtml
- Java:
  ImageJ
  http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/
  OpenCV Java
  http://ubaa.net/shared/processing/opencv/
- Python:
  Python Imaging Library
  http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/
- ImageMagick offers binding for a large variety of languages: Ada C, Ch, COM+, C++, Java, Lisp, Pascal, Php, Perl, Ruby ...

But the main point is that image processing requires very good performance. A typical image contains millions of points to process. The efficiency issue is even more critical for 3d images, which are very common in medical imaging.
In practice, the main image processing libraries are written in C++ or have binding to C++.
You can take a look at this one [Milena](http://www.lrde.epita.fr/cgi-bin/twiki/view/Olena/Milena) (offering python bindings). And here is a non exhaustive list of image processing libraries in C++ (each offering various binding for different languages or web services)
http://www.lrde.epita.fr/cgi-bin/twiki/view/Olena/SimilarProjects

Answer (score 1):

For python:
PIL - Image Library
PyOpenCV
VTK

Answer (score 0):

You can use Boost GIL(generic image library) for C++.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/gil/doc/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Just about any language does.  Google can help you here.  Type in [(language) image processing](http://google.com/search?q=perl+image+processing) to see what libraries are available for whichever languages you're looking at.  [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) is one of the older and more well-known libraries that is usable from several different languages.

Answer (score 0):

The [Python Imaging Library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) is a very useful low-level library. You won't get C++-like performance with an interpreted language, but if that's not important, you should look at it.